# 2 Digit 7 Segment Display Driver

Tags: avr, atmega, 7segmentdisplay

I need to display the temperature acquired by my LM35 on a 2 digit 7 segment display. What I have is **LTD383-R2 Common Anode** Display. Datasheet [here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.icchip.info%2Fdatasheet%2FLTD383E-R2.pdf&ei=v1UmVK3KMo7kuQSHt4LYDw&usg=AFQjCNFRI7_f6-BoVQylfR5vvlaOtW7g4Q&sig2=6Ce1x3dNul86o3Sk630kdQ&bvm=bv.76247554,d.c2E/).

The display has 1 Anode pin + 14 Cathode pins for he 14 segments.

Any idea on the best way to drive this (with least components)? I am using Atmega328.

The options that came to mind were

1. Use a decoder. Google search came up with DS8669 from TI, but it seems that IC is now obsolete.
2. Go the usual route of using a ULN2803 darlington array IC + 74HC595 shift register. But this would mean using 4 IC's in total (2 for each digit of the display)

Thanks !

Comment: If you don't have enough high-drive outputs to directly drive it from the Atmega, you might want to consider a different display. You could also use the '595s to directly drive the segments. Variants exist with DMOS output transistors (not all that cheap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another 16 bit shift register with constant current sinks is the TLC 5926, datasheet available [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5926.pdf)

Comment: Single ic solution, though I'm partial to the i2c version myself.

Comment: Thanks ! Looks like just what I need :). Whats the part number for the i2c version of this chip?

Comment: I don't know whether it's second-sourced or not, but from TI, it's the TLC59116.

Answer (score 1):

Options:

- drive the segments directly from your uc. using the 200mA figure from the absolute maxima (which is strictly speaking *wrong* to do) you have ~ 14 mA per segment. You won't see the difference between 14 and 20 mA.
- if you have the uc pins but want to use the full 20mA you can use two ULN2003 chips.
- if you don't have enough uc pins you can go the 595 route. It has a total supply current limit of 70 mA (again: only mentioned in the wretched maxima section), so you have 10 mA per segment. Would be OK for me.
- if you really want this display AND you have only 3 uc pins AND you want the full 20 mA per segment, sigh, you must go the 4 chips solution (or something equivalent, using a chip that is probably more expensive and more difficult to get).
- ditch the display and get a more standard one with 2 anodes and shared cathodes (or the other way round), so you can multiplex. If you get a low-current version (use high-brightness displays that work perfect with 1 or 2 mA per segment) you can drive it directly from 10 uc pins.

Comment: Thanks for laying out the options. Ideally would love to g with the last one, but unfortunately here in India they are not easy to acquire unless in big quantities.

Comment: Why not go with the first option? The difference in brightness will be barely noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the STP16CP05 for plain shift-register operation, or the TLC59116 if I want PWM control of each segment.

The STP16CP05 is the same kind of shift register as a 75HC595 but each output is a constant current sink.

The TLC59116 is an I2C PWM driver which again is a constant current sink.

Both have 16 outputs for driving all 16 segments of your LED display with only 1 resistor and a couple of deccoupling capacitors.  Can't get fewer components than that really.

Here's an example with the TLC59116 [I sell on eBay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/TLC59116-I2C-Dual-7-Segment-Red-LED-Display-for-Arduino-chipKIT-Launchpad-Pi-/191187743319).

Comment: How about some full disclosure, that's your auction Majenko...

Comment: I said I use them didn't I?